# Python logging stdout and stderr based on level

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

Using Python 3 logging, how can I specify that `logging.debug()` and `logging.info()` should go to `stdout` and `logging.warning()` and `logging.error()` go to `stderr`?

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question, but have you considered writing your own logging functions to achieve this? You know, like 'logDebug()' -> Print to stdout, etc.

Comment: I want to continue to use Python's built-in logging. Just need to change the stream dynamically it seems.

Answer (score 1):

You can create separate loggers for each stream like this:

```py
import logging
import sys

logging.basicConfig(format="%(levelname)s %(message)s")

stdout_logger = logging.Logger(name="stdout_logger", level=logging.DEBUG)
stderr_logger = logging.Logger(name="stderr_logger", level=logging.DEBUG)

stdout_handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
stderr_handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stderr)

stdout_logger.addHandler(hdlr=stdout_handler)
stderr_logger.addHandler(hdlr=stderr_handler)

stdout_logger.info("this will output to stdout")
stderr_logger.info("this will output to stderr")
```

Then if you want to log something on 'debug' or 'info' level you can just use stdout_logger. For 'warning' and 'error' level messages use stderr_logger.

Answer (score 0):

How to do this kind of thing is [documented in the logging cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#custom-handling-of-levels), and though the example levels/destinations in the cookbook recipe are slightly different from those in your question, there should be enough information there for you to arrive at a solution. The key thing is using a filter function and attaching it to a handler.